# how to write a gradle task that calls two other tasks?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle

I use intellij IDEA,

I have two gradle tasks: `clean resources` and `generate new resources`.

```
task resources_cleaner_fresh(type: JavaExec) {
    jvmArgs = ["-Xms1024m","-Xmx1024m"]
    main = "com.m.ResourcesCleanerRunner"
}

task BL_generate_warmup(type: JavaExec) {
    jvmArgs = ["-Xms1024m","-Xmx1024m"]
    main = "com.m.BaselineGeneratorRunner"
}
```

how can I write one unified gradle task that call them one after the other?

Comment: have you tried using `dependsOn`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use task dependencies like:

`task BL_generate_warmup(type: JavaExec) {
  dependsOn resources_cleaner_fresh
  ...`

and run `gradle BL_generate_warmup`. Rinse and repeat this pattern if you need to call this before some other task is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in build.gradle

```
resources_cleaner_fresh.dependsOn BL_generate_warmup
```

Then, simply execute `resources_cleaner_fresh` command on gradle task to run both of them at once.